# Heroku ruby buildpack error - undefined local variable or method `install_language_pack_gems'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.0

I just upgraded my Rails 3.2.16 app's ruby version from 1.9.2 to 2.0.0 and everything is working fine locally. However, when trying to push to Heroku, it's failing to compile.

It detects the ruby version, starts installing dependencies, then crashes:

```
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
   Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
   Old: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:760:in `block in purge_bundler_cache': undefined local variable or method `install_language_pack_gems' for #<LanguagePack::Rails3:0x00000000c1d090> (NameError)
```

Seems like something simple, but I don't particularly want to mess with the buildpack.

This also happens for an app running on Ruby 2.0

```
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:760:in `block in purge_bundler_cache': undefined local variable or method `install_language_pack_gems' for #<LanguagePack::Rails4:0x00000002084a60> (NameError)
```

Comment: I just ran into this as well when upgrading my ruby version. Heroku had a maintenance window an hour or so ago...I wonder if this is related.

Comment: Ah yes, just got the same thing...

Comment: @fighella were you upgrading your ruby version?

Comment: I was hoping it was failing just during the maintenance window, but happened after too. I think it's related to the buildpack, which they've been patching and messing with for the last couple weeks. I opened an issue as well, so will keep you guys updated if I see anything there: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/218

Comment: I got the same thing and I have the app running on Ruby 2.0

Comment: @John no. It was using 2.0.0 and not changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like it is not using the latest ruby buildpack. I was able to solve this by setting the `BUILDPACK_URL`

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```